# send and receive sms using GSM server

Tags: c#, sms, sms-gateway

i download send and receive sms using GSM server.program from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem)

but when send sms from mobile to GSM server, sms didn't display in GSM server.why?
please help me.

Comment: Article says you need to connect GSM Modem from COM port, do you have it?

Comment: yes, i connect this. send sms from GSM to mobile successfully. but didn't display received sms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use gsm modem to send and receive here i used both two examples and they work perfectly:
[Send sms by gsm modem](http://sharp-coders.blogspot.com/2011/12/send-sms-using-at-commands-via-gms.html)

[sned and receive sms by gsm modem](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem)

Comment: thank you for your answer,i, use from this link that you said:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem but didn't worked.

Comment: there are some requirements you must have GSM modem and set baudrate to 9600 it must work and can you tell me what kind of error you get?

Comment: yeah, i set this setting. but didn't display.